# I've moved a WP Website, and now my Homepage is blank

Tags: php, wordpress

I moved my WordPress website to another server and URL, and now my homepage is coming up blank, even when I preview it in the dashboard.

EDIT:  I tried to jerryrig it so that an index.html file would redirect to a faux homepage (start.php), and I'd then change my menus.  But when I used my homepage template, I got a blank result, even if the page wasn't set as my home page.

Comment: Were you using a static home page? If you enter urls to other pages on the site directly can you access them? Many things go awry when you move wordpress, and you have to manually reconfigure them.

Comment: Here's a very detailed guide on how to move Wordpress. Those PHP warnings were almost certainly already present before they move, but they get hidden when WP_DEBUG is set to false. http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 1):

your problem is a plugin Contact Form 7 ( I just deactivate this plugin).

Pdt: Change the admin password.

[image]

Comment: pdt: your other site also has an admin default password

Comment: With Contact Form 7 deactivated, the problem still exists.  I'm reactivating it now.

Comment: the weirdest thing is that you change the default theme by one the screen was blank. try placing as true in the function define('WP_DEBUG', false); in the file wp-config.php

Comment: Please don't log in to my sites.  But thank you for the reminder to make real passwords.

Comment: And don't change anything.  It's working right now, albeit in a roundabout manner.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible these error log errors may have existed on your other site- they don't seem like deal breakers.

Here are some things I often try to troubleshoot when come across problems in moving sites:

- Flush permalinks (Settings->Permalinks and hit Save)
- Make sure you changed the url in wp_options (home and siteurl)
- If your Dashboard is coming up, that's a good sign. Make sure your database has been imported, and that the correct theme is activated
- To troublesheet, start deactivating plugins (try deactivating all first and add them on one by one)
- Check that the PHP (and MySQL) version of your new server matches your old server (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)
- Check that the settings for PHP shorthand are the same on both servers (broke one of mine for me once: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)
- Check that your php.ini file for your new server matches your old one to some extent- something breaking could be due to a different setting (this option is similar to the previous suggestions)

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried your first four suggestions.  Thanks.
Is it likely that the PHP or MySQL versions are different, since all of my other pages work?  I think the problem is a certain template.

Answer (score 0):

You likely had this issue before, but error reporting was set not to show E_NOTICE. This is the default, to show all errors except E_NOTICE

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: So this isn't the reason my homepage is coming up blank?

Comment: Well the notice is hitting output before the headers. If you hide the notice, the headers don't fail, and your site MAY work or you may be presented with a new error.

Comment: This is not _the_ way to show errors in Wordpress. In Wordpress, you go to wp-config.php and set WP_DEBUG to true instead of false, which is what it usually is.

Comment: Either using php.ini  - `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE` or .htaccess - `php_flag error_reporting 1` Where 1 can be replaced with a value from this page http://us3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: @Jason Alright but it makes no sense since it's not his problem. Wordpress decides error reporting level, ergo it has not changed. If he doesn't want to show notices, he should just leave WP_DEBUG at false and it will never be shown to users. Who cares it there's an entry in an error log somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to move wordpress server is to use a importer .There are many importer plugins for that purpose .I suggest you to have a fresh installation and than import the posts that would solve your problem in the process

Comment: I used the Duplicator plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that does an output before the header is send....
if you see the message, cannot modify header.... click on show source of the browser and look what invokes the output directly before the first `<br />`

```
<br /> 
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information … in <b>…</b> on line <b>…</b><br />
```